# Accessing List Constructor

Tags: c#, list, constructor

First of all apologize if the terminology is not right. I have a constructor like this below:

```
public class A
{
  public int B { get; set; }
  public ICollection<C> C { get; set; }     
}

public class C
{
    public int D { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to access information on D like this:

```
List<A> listA = New List<A>;
if (listA != null)
{
      foreach (var temp in listA)
      {
         if (temp.C.D.contains(123)) --> got an error here
         {
         }
       }
  }
```

How do I get information on D?

Comment: Well, `temp.C` returns a **collection** of elements of type `C`, not a single element. You have to indicate which of those you want to access.

Comment: I see no constructors in this code.

Comment: `List<A> listA = New List<A>;`  this doesn't compile.  Is this the constructor you're referring to?  `new` is lower-cased, and you are missing the parenthesis for the call.

Comment: First off. try to create names that are not unambiguous.  ICollection<C> C .. how about ICollection<C> Cs or ICollection<C> MyCs  ?  A well crafted question will help your cause.  second.... temp.C is a collection.    try temp.C.Select(myc => myc.D) or google "linq select" and "linq selectmany" .. these are "flatten out" functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is a collection of objects, you need to loop again to access C.

[Also In C#, constructor is a special method which is invoked automatically at the time of object creation. It is used to initialize the data members of new object generally. The constructor in C# has the same name as class or struct. There can be two types of constructors in C#.](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1ASUM_enGB819GB819&ei=gFDMXPejDbuo1fAP4vGioAM&q=what%20is%20a%20constructor%20in%20c%23&oq=what%20is%20a%20constructor%20in%20c%23&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30l8.885.3432..3776...2.0..0.93.489.8....2..0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i333.NiPheOz4zBQ)

```
List<A> listA = new List<A>;
    if (listA != null)
    {
          foreach (var temp in listA)
          {
             foreach(var d in temp.C) 
             {
                 //ToDo Interact with d.D
             }
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

PWT's answer is great, but if you did want to do a one line `if` statement, you could do this, using System.Linq. This gives the same result as you were trying to achieve in your question.

```cs
List<A> listA = new List<A>();
if (listA != null)
{
    foreach (var temp in listA)
    {
        if (temp.C.Any(c => c.D == 123))
        {
            // todo your logic
        }
    }
}
```